# 2nd HD added to laptop. Eating battery life

Tags: battery

I replaced my main laptop hard drive with a 240GB SSD. Ordered one of the faux optical drives that allow you store a second hard drive where your CD-ROM use to be. I'm able to access both drives successfully, my only problem - the battery life is literally about a 1/2 or a 1/3 of what it use to be before this new hard drive arrangement.

I'd read forum posts about the old Ubuntu bug where it can continuously cycle your drives. I am not accessing this drive. Not reading or indexing the data on it. It is my Windows 7 NTFS drive that came with the system. I was going to format it and use it as additional storage but now I'm debating just putting my optical drive back in.

I could understand if the battery life diminished slightly but if I'm not actually moving or using the drive AT ALL. Why does it affect life so much? Is there a way to correct it or possibly leave it completely unmounted unless otherwise needed? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than removing the drive entirely, which would certainly work, why don't you set some energy saving settings like the ones suggested  [here](http://www.havetheknowhow.com/Configure-the-server/Spin-down-idle-drives.html)
.

Answer (score 0):

In Disks select the drive and click More Actions then Standby Now, although you will have to do this every time you start the computer.

Alternatively you I think you could edit fstab and have the drive not mount, but thats for another poster to answer.

Answer (score 0):

user142712, I went to the Disks section and was able to turn off automount. I also saw the option to Standby Now. I'll look into automatically running that command after login if I don't see the desired results. I'll be testing it tonight for several hours and will report back.

Jason, I will also try spinning down the disks to see if I can get more performance from my battery. Thank you both.